# Habitat TDS Version - Sync Items to Sitecore

Tags: tds, habitat

Keep in mind I'm a relative newbie to `TDS`, but looking through some of the documentation, I'm not sure I have found an answer that solidifies I'm doing something wrong.

I've got TDS installed and pulled down the TDS version of `Habitat` from GitHub, restored `NuGet packages` fine and published to target. As the last step to get set up, I was unsure, if there was a certain order to Sync the items with Sitecore or if it could be done all at once. Going to the solution node in VS and choosing `Sync all TDS Projects using History` didn't seem to do it, so then I started going project by project and choosing `Sync with Sitecore`

This is where I'm having difficulty because TDS throws errors. Most errors I'm seeing are

```
> TDS not being able to update Standard Values due to the parent
> template missing the fields such as '__Masters' and '__Created':
```

[image]

So, I'm wondering is there a particular order to sync, is there a more efficient option, or am I just completely going about this in the wrong way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The dependency is Project > Foundation > Feature. So in project/Habitat right click on the TDS project and click "Deploy". That will send it, no questions asked. Then do Foundation. NOTE: Not part of this question, but you may consider getting the Unicorn version of Habitat. There is a gulp task for deploying the Unicorn serialization.

Comment: The TDS version in Github has the correct build order setup.
Selecting Build > Deploy, or right clicking the solution and selecting 'Deploy Solution' will do the correct order.
No gulp tasks, or per-project sequences needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right click on your Solution tab and check the Project Dependencies. Ensure that the Build Order reflects the proper dependency order:

1. Foundation
2. Feature
3. Project

... and that in general, templates are pushed before their content. If need be, use the Dependencies tab to adjust project dependencies to adjust the build order.

Then, and only then, try a Build > Deploy. This will push all your TDS content, according to the Build Order, without having to manually sync each project.

Comment: Correct. When setting up the TDS solution, I ensured that the Project Build Order reflects this. So grabbing the latest from Github, and just doing a Build > Deploy will correctly push these in the correct order.

Comment: Accepting this because it does answer the original question. I think I've got something more sinister going on, however. It seems TDS is intermittently not able to reach the target website, though those settings are correct. All of a sudden, the website throws a compiler error - The compiler failed with error code 255 - So, there's more research to do which will probably prompt another question! Thanks to Sean as well on this.

Comment: If you updated your Tds.Global.config.user file with the correct URL and Path to the website, then TDS will work fine.
If the site is down, I'd recommend a reinstall first, and deploy the solution again. Also, the TDS-latest branch is the most up-to-date, so I would recommend using that.